# Generate PDF from EPS in python

Tags: python, crop, eps

Currently I am generating EPS files in python in a straightforward manner. For various reasons it would be more convenient to go a step further and output a PDF cropped exactly to the same dimensions as the EPS file and containing it. How would I go about doing this in python with a minimum of fuss?

Comment: Did you try with reportlabs?

Comment: No, I am not familiar with reportlabs. What would be the simplest way to achieve my goal in reportlabs?

Comment: I feel like I used to use the `eps2pdf` unix tool for this sort of thing.  If you have it installed, you might be able to invoke it using a `subprocess`.

Comment: Yeah, reportlabs can help you with your PDF reports. Try it and then teach me how do you solve your question.